# proper way to stop software RAID before system shutdown

Tags: debian, raid, mdadm, software-raid, reboot

This should be straightforward, but I have been unable to find a direct answer by searching.

I find that if I unmount an mdadm-managed array and then either (1) unplug the array, (2) power off the enclosure housing the array, (3) reboot the system, or (4) shut down the system, then `mdadm` issues an alert about a fail event having been detected:

```
This is an automatically generated mail message from mdadm
running on <hostname>

A Fail event had been detected on md device /dev/md0.

It could be related to component device /dev/sdc1.

Faithfully yours, etc.

P.S. The /proc/mdstat file currently contains the following:

Personalities : [raid1] 
md0 : active (auto-read-only) raid1 sdc1[1](F) sdb1[0]
      1952984000 blocks super 1.2 [2/1] [U_]

unused devices: <none>
```

The RAID appears to be fine and can be readily resumed. To avoid generating this alert, must I execute `mdadm --stop /dev/md0` after unmounting and before either disconnecting or rebooting? For routine system reboot and shutdown, should this command be included within a script in `/etc/init.d/` and symbolically linked in `/etc/rc0.d/` and `/etc/rc6.d/`?

Thank you for clarifying.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you need to stop the array before removing the disks.  In general, the order of operations is this, where completing each step makes it possible to do the next step:

1. Stop any programs using filesystems on the array.
2. Unmount all filesystems on the array.
3. Stop the array.
4. Power down the array disks.

If you're using LVM, there's a step 2.5 where you deactivate the LVM volume mappings, but I don't know the correct way to do this.